# How to transfer MySQL database from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: server, windows, mysql, transfer

I want to transfer my database from WAMP on my local machine to my Ubuntu VPS.

Can I just copy the folder of the database from `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data` to `/var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: Ehm I would dump the databases and load them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) is the general method to copy a database over.

Create a dump on windows:

```
mysqldump -u [USER] -p [DATABASE] > [BACKUP]
```

Copy the file over to Ubuntu and restore it in Ubuntu:

```
mysql -u [USER] -p [DATABASE] <./[BACKUP]
```

- both commands are done from the shell (not from within MySQL).

Comment: in windows with shell u mean CMD or mysql console ?

Comment: here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hsOk0XcYC4 (you need the shell (cmd) not mysql prompt)

Comment: thx but i have this error 
"mysqldump is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: You need to change directory to where you run mysql from.

Comment: @MahmoudSenSei sorry I am not a windows user. you are on your own ;)

Comment: Thx i just found the solution, i searched for mysqldump in Wamp and copied it in c:\windows\system32

Comment: @Rinzwind last thing , should i create an ampty database in the server to dump in it my new database ?

Comment: Yes. A dump does not make the db itself (you also need permissions to it ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind permissions ?

Comment: u mean the user should have all privileges ?

Comment: permissions as in GRANT PRIVILEGES etc.

Comment: what if mysql crashed and won't start on windows. how can i transfer database from windows to ubuntu in such case?